# Login to OS X Server User Account from Local Computer

Tags: osx-server, open-directory, login-screen, ldap

I have OS X Server installed on a Mac Mini. I've created several user accounts, one of which is:

Account Name: Bob
Password: abc123

From the Mac Mini's login screen I can choose "Server" (main account) "Bob" (Bobs account) and "Other…" OS X Server Accounts, from "Other…" if I input Bobs credentials it will log me in.

I also have a MacBook Air. I would like to be able to select from the Login Screen "Other..." input Bobs credentials and have it login to Bobs account, or any other User Account for that matter.

My Server is setup as private with the server address: server.network.private

Following some Googled instructions as well as Apple's very own instructions I have:

1. Setup an Open Directory with

   Username: diradmin
   Password: abc123
2. Then on the MacBook Air gone into System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Options and clicked Join next to Network Account Server, inputted my server (server.network.private) with diradmin credentials and connected. Great.
3. I've also ticked Allow Network Users to Login and Login Window and selected All Users.
4. I was assuming this would allow my MacBook Air to login to the "Bob" account by selecting "Other…" from the login window although there is no "Other…" option.

I then setup a VPN, basic credentials, logged into it on the macbook air and still not much has changed. I am able to share screens with the "Bob" account form my MacBook Air by logging in by clicking Share Screen… from the Finder under Shared → Network Server and then clicking Log In but this obviously requires the MacBook Air to already be logged into an account before it can share screens which is not suitable.

Is there any way to simply login to the OS X Server User Account from the MacBook Air's login screen  via the Other… like it does on the Mac Mini's login screen?

<sup>Operating System: OS X 10.9 Mavericks

OS X Server: Version 3</sup>